# jquery selectors for selecting the attribute node, not the element node?

Tags: jquery, attributes, element, selector, nodes

Does jQuery have any selectors that can select the attribute node rather than the element node?  I don't mean something like this:

```
$('.some-thing').attr('some-attr');
```

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
$('.some-thing[some-attr]');
```

(Except that the above still gets the .some-thing nodes (but filtered to only include those with the "some-attr" attribute.)

Thoughts?

Comment: You only want the `href="http://www.example.com"` out of the `<a href="http://www.example.com">click</a>`? (Just an example)

Comment: Right.  That's what I'm going for.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in the way you want it. The bit `$('.some-thing')` is the selector that selects elements, not an attribute of it. I'm afraid you have to use `$('.some-thing').attr('some-attr')` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
$('[some-attr]')
```

This will get all the elements that have the particular attribute.

Comment: I'm just looking for the attribute node - not the element node.  Make sense?  (See putvande's question above.)

Answer (score 0):

Sample [link](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) - `$('input[value="Hot Fuzz"]')`

Search more about Jquery Selector.

Comment: That still gets the input element, right?  Not the value attribute as a node?